# Android java Screen as an button

Tags: java, android

How can I make the screen as a button?
I want to make a game where you click on the hole screen not just a button in Xml.
I want this code to be in Java not Xml.
Anyone with a tip out there?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very generic, perhaps this will help you to get started. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish with this 'Screen Button' perhaps it would be easier for us to point you in the right direction.

You need to implement the following method in your View :

`public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {}`

Then you'll be able to grab the coordinates were the screen was touched with :

`event.getX()` and `event.getY()`

**EDIT :** You can detect wether the action is a click or release by checking the `MotionEvent` like so :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch(action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // Do click work here ...
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // Do release work here ...
        break;
        }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Other type of actions can also be checked via other `MotionEvent` :

`MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`
`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`

Comment: Thanks, I will start from there and see how it turns out.

Comment: Hi, it work but do you have the same statment for when you are not touching the screen? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me here. You want to know when the user isn't touching the screen ?

Comment: No, I mean when you touch the screen and you take finger out.

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, and covers what you needed answered. Please mark it as answered using the checkmark, so if other in your situation can find it more easily and hopefully get their problem solved without even asking for help.